Creating and Updating Column Json data
This is inside my Column 'reviewsDistribution' @myDataBase
{
    "oneStar": 0,
    "twoStar": 0,
    "threeStar": 1,
    "fourStar": 2,
    "fiveStar": 10
}

This is what is inserted really.
It's a json type column
"{\"oneStar\":0,\"twoStar\":0,\"threeStar\":1,\"fourStar\":2,\"fiveStar\":10}"


I wanted to show this at Create Method
I've tried:
$this->crud->addField(['name' => 'reviewsDistribution', 'type' => 'table']);

Also:
$this->crud->addField(['name' => 'reviewsDistribution', 'type' => 'json']); // ERROR

Also:
$this->crud->addField(['name' => 'reviewsDistribution', 'type' => 'array']); // ERROR 500

But it does not shows as I wanted
How can I do that???
I can Update those values via
    public function showJsonData() {
        $place = Place::first();
        $reviewsDistribution = json_decode($place->reviewsDistribution, true);
        return response()->json($reviewsDistribution);
        return response()->json($reviewsDistribution['fiveStar']);
    }


    public function updateJsonData() {
        $place = Place::first();
        $reviewsDistribution = json_decode($place->reviewsDistribution, true);
        $reviewsDistribution['fiveStar'] = 10;
        $place->reviewsDistribution = json_encode($reviewsDistribution);
        $place->save();
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'FiveStar updated successfully]);
    }

And It works

There is the Table type field, you can check this on docs, this is a Pro field, so you need to have a license to use it.
If you follow instructions, to Cast or if need special format to Decode, this will work.

{
"oneStar": 0,
"twoStar": 0,
"threeStar": 1,
"fourStar": 2,
"fiveStar": 10
}
Is this correct??
Beacuse I don't see those values in my TABLE FIELD

Also, If I try so save it... it gives me....... htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
