Cannot find 'array' field view in any of the regular locations
I'm trying to show in Laravel Backpack an array
But It seems that the array field is not present in my installation
{
    "oneStar": 0,
    "twoStar": 0,
    "threeStar": 1,
    "fourStar": 2,
    "fiveStar": 10
}


This gives me an error

$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'reviewsDistribution',
    'label' => 'reviewsDistribution',
    'type' => 'array',
    'entity_singular' => 'reviewsDistribution', // used on the "Add X" button
    'columns' => [
        'key' => 'Star Rating',
        'value' => 'Count'
    ],
]);


Cannot find 'array' field view in any of the regular locations.
PS: I have Backpack Pro installed...

There is not "array field" in Backpack, is this a custom field?
You can check the available fields here.
Cheers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78852869/creating-and-updating-column-json-data

It's a response from this user
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78852869/creating-and-updating-column-json-data
